# How to achieve oflag=direct in dd on MacOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

I have installed `gdd` on MacOS.

I figured out both `dd` and `gdd` don't support `oflag=direct` option.

```
 ‘direct’
      Use direct I/O for data, avoiding the buffer cache.  Note that
      the kernel may impose restrictions on read or write buffer
      sizes.  For example, with an ext4 destination file system and
      a Linux-based kernel, using ‘oflag=direct’ will cause writes
      to fail with ‘EINVAL’ if the output buffer size is not a
      multiple of 512.
```

<sup>from dd(1) on Linux</sup>

And the built-in `dd` doesn't even support `conv=fsync`.

I am wondering how to achieve `oflag=direct` in `dd` or `gdd` on MacOS?

Comment: Superb question. Is your end goal performance speed of the copy?

Comment: @bmike no. If I want to test the performance, I will use `fio` command. I just posted a comment about why I want this option in the answer's 4th comment. You can have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How to achieve it depends on what you are trying to do:

If you're just trying to copy data from one disk to another, which is a very common use case for `dd`, you would typically achieve something similar to `oflag=direct` simply by using the right block device.

I.e. for example if you're copying like this:

```
dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/dev/disk1 bs=1m
```

You can speed it up by using raw disk access like this:

```
dd if=/dev/rdisk0 of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

Note that the names of the block devices have been prefixed with "r", which stands for a "raw" device.

If you're not copying between block devices like that, there's still a way to get something similar to `oflag=direct` on Linux:

The reason why it's not implemented the same way as Linux, and thus not directly ported over when porting GNU dd to macOS, is that the macOS kernel simply does not support the `O_DIRECT` flag for `fcntl`.

The flag came to the Linux kernel about about 20 years ago as an "inspiration" from the similarly named flag in SGI IRIX. You set it on an file descriptor in order to bypass the normal caching subsystem.

However macOS originally did not have its cache configuration per file descriptor - instead it had it per `vnode`. Think of this as the difference between having the cache configuration set for a file per se, and having the cache configuration set for a particular instance of an open file. I.e. in the latter case, two different programs could be working on the same file with different cache configurations.

This meant that back then (i.e. 20+ years ago) macOS could not adopt O_DIRECT from SGI IRIX like Linux did, but they instead opted to create an option named F_NOCACHE. This also turns the ordinary caching subsystem off, but does per file instead of per file descriptor. Later on, macOS actually changed the workings of the operating system to have the cache configuration per file descriptor instead of per `vnode`, so now it's more or less the same thing.

You might ask - what did Linux users do before they got `O_DIRECT`? - They actually used the same type of "raw" devices as macOS also offers, and that I described above. Instead of prefixing them with "r" they were typically prefixed by "raw", but otherwise it is the same concept.

In practice, if you're just copying disks with dd, it is convenient to just use the raw devices. If you're trying to achieve something else, you probably belong to a niche use case, which isn't directly supported. To me it sounds like the easiest way forward there would be to change the `gdd` implementation and add a `fcntl` for `F_NOCACHE`, similarly to the `O_DIRECT` one that has been removed from the macOS port.

However, depending on what you're trying to do, you should be aware of slight differences in the semantics of the flags. For example if you want to use `O_DIRECT` in order to do benchmarking, you need to take additional care. `F_NOCACHE` is namely different from `O_DIRECT` in that while it does not add data to the cache, it will read data from the cache if it is already there for some reason. This will increase performance, but that might not be what you want for benchmarking.

Comment: This is one of the most polite, detailed and thoughtful ways to say “so, tell me what you really are trying to do here…”. Superb answer to a technical question.

Comment: Thanks ;-) I hope it will be useful no matter what the use case is :-)

Comment: You’ve made this question great and an instant bookmark in my eyes. I’m tempted to benchmark `asr` vs `dd` since we know Apple engineers are motivated to make `asr` fast since they wait for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and professional answer. I didn't expect such a good answer. The reason why I am asking this is because when I am using dd to write to a hard drive, I found out it didn't actually write to that hard drive. The problem is similar to https://abbbi.github.io/dd/ but it's not the same. You can use that URL as a reference for why I am concerning about those flags. Thank you very much again.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some more details about your problem - i.e. exactly what commands did you use, which type of drive, what did you do after the command (i.e. for example unplugging USB-drives or whatever). You problem does not seem to be about O_DIRECT at all, as it not deciding in ensuring that data is actually written to disk, you want the O_SYNC flag instead.

Comment: The background story and how I found `oflag` option is: I tried to zero out a hard drive. So `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4096`. The command succeeds in the end. I even ran `sync` command after the `dd` command. But the drive is NOT zeroed out by checking hdd afterwards. I think the writting to the drive operation stopped somewhere in the middle. So I would like to find a way to make sure dd does NOT use any cache and direct IO to hdd. If this is nothing to do with oflag=direct, I will still ask this question because I want to know how to avoid cache and do direct IO anyway. Thanks.

Comment: No, this really hasn't got anything to do with O_DIRECT. Your problem seem to be that you're using asynchronous I/O and thus not getting direct feedback on errors. I would create a new question on that - just specify what you're trying to accomplish, the hardware you're using, etc. without assuming what the underlying cause is, and I think you will get better answers that way.

Comment: However, I would say that what you're describing is definitely not what you would expect - so I'm thinking perhaps you left some important information out so far. Could you describe fully what you're doing? - I.e. is this a broken hard drive you're working on? - is it not really a hard drive, but an SSD? is it connected through some unconventional way? These details are important.

Comment: Also please describe how you're making sure that the drive is really filled with zeroes afterwards. It might be that the drive was actually zeroed out, but you're doing some incorrectly when checking it. It also might be that you have forgotten to unmount the drive, so that the operating system is writing data to it while you're zeroing it out or something like that?

Comment: Also note: If your real purpose here is to erase the drive in order to give it to a third party (or to get rid of it), then zeroing the drive is most often not the best way to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. It's a 3.5inch hard drive, not a SSD. It's connected with USB (in an external enclosure). I use [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/559772/) way to verify if it's filled with zeros (with `od` cmd). It didn't have a partition and a filesystem so it's not mounted. I checked the zeros after powering down and powering up the drive. I agree with you that is another question. I may ask it in a new question later. For this question, I am happy to learn the details about what happened with O_DIRECT on MacOS, and thanks a lot for the answer really. :)